# Combine data frames from a vector of names

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have an issue that I thought easy to solve, but I did not manage to find a solution. 
I have a large number of data frames that I want to bind by rows. To avoid listing the names of all data frames, I used "paste0" to quickly create a vector of names of the data frames. The problem is that I do not manage to make the rbind function identify the data frames from this vector of name.
More explicitely:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = sample(1:5,5), x2 =  sample(1:5,5))
df2 <- data.frame(x1 = sample(1:5,5), x2 =  sample(1:5,5))
idvec <- noquote(c(paste0("df",c(1,2))))
> [1] df1 df2
```

What I would like to get:

```
dftot <- rbind(df1,df2)
   x1 x2
1   4  1
2   5  2
3   1  3
4   3  4
5   2  5
6   5  3
7   1  4
8   2  2
9   3  5
10  4  1

dftot <- rbind(idvec)
>       [,1]  [,2] 
> idvec "df1" "df2"
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are aiming to do here. Do you want to be mark particular rows as having come from a particular dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are multiple objects in the global environment with the pattern `df` followed by digits, one option is using `ls` to find all those objects with the `pattern` argument.  Wrapping it with `mget` gets the values in the `list`, which we can `rbind` with `do.call`.

```
v1 <- ls(pattern='^df\\d+')
`row.names<-`(do.call(rbind,mget(v1)), NULL)
```

If we know the objects, another option is `paste` to create a vector of object names and then do as before.

```
v1 <- paste0('df', 1:2)
 `row.names<-`(do.call(rbind,mget(v1)), NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know about the function mget, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: @user34771  Glad to know that it worked. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

This should give the result:

```
dfcount <- 2
dftot <- df1 #initialise
for(n in 2:dfcount){dftot <- rbind(dftot, eval(as.name(paste0("df", as.character(n)))))}
```

`eval(as.name(variable_name))` reads the data frames from strings matching their names.

Comment: Thank you very much, the eval function is very useful too.

Comment: Glad it's helpful.  I only discovered it today.  Before that, if I wanted to refer to a variable by a string, I'd have R write a script file and then source it!